# Cantor Set and Cantor Function Plus x

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $g(x)=x+C(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$, where $C(x)$ is the Cantor-Lebesgue function.

Let $Z$ be the Cantor Set, which has Lebesgue measure zero.

How would we show that $g(Z)$ does ***not*** have measure zero?

---

What I know is $C(Z)=[0,1]$, i.e. the Cantor function maps the Cantor set to $[0,1]$. So intuitively, I would suppose $g(Z)=[0,2]$?

How would we show that? (I only need the weaker condition that $g(Z)$ has positive measure.)

Thanks!

Comment: @Henry Please see https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_zaboronski/analysisiii/cantor.pdf page 3, proposition 2.1.4

Comment: fair enough....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $\mathcal{C}$ the cantor set.

Note that $[0,1] \setminus \mathcal{C}$ is the disjoint union of line segments of where we define $x\mapsto C(x)$ to be constant (middle thirds). On each of this, $g(x)$ is a function of the form $x\mapsto x + b$ where $b$ is som constant (related to the construction of $x\mapsto C(x)$). Therefore $g$ is an affine map on each of this, and so it preserves their measure (lebesgue measure is translation invariant + the map $x\mapsto x$ is linear with determinant $1$).

That being said: $m \left( g\left([0,1]\setminus \mathcal{C}\right) \right)= m([0,1]\setminus \mathcal{C}) = 1$

Now, $g(x)$ is continuous and stricly increasing (this is obvious since $x\mapsto C(x)$ is non-decreasing and $x\mapsto x$ is stricly increasing), $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1)=2$ and so $g([0,1]) = [0,2]$.

This together with what we showed at the begining gives us the desired result:  $g(\mathcal{C}) =1 >0$.